# CV@R/AV@R/Expected Shortfall dual Formulation

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, lagrange-multiplier, duality-theorems

I'm really struggling with the dual Problem of the AV@R

$AV@R (Y)=\underset{Z}{\sup} \{ \, \mathbb{E}(YZ) \, , \, 0\le Z \le 1/(1-\alpha) \, , \, \mathbb{E}=(Z) = 1 \} $

By formulating the linear dual Problem one should get:

$AV@R (Y)=\underset{x \in \mathbb{R}}{\min} \,\{ x \, + \, 1/(1-\alpha) \, \mathbb{E} \, (\max \{0,Y-x\})\} $

According to different papers it seems tob trivial but unfortunately I couldn't calculate it. Could someone pleas explain it to me?

Thank you very much

Comment: What is $AV@R$?

Comment: @MPW It is the "average" value at risk, which is better known as expected tail loss.   It measures the expected loss in a tail of a distribution.  It is also called Conditional Value at Risk.

Comment: Ah yes. ${}{}{}{}{}{}$